# Infertility data: causes and solutions

Tags: data-request, medical, research, biology

I am looking for a list of all possible causes of infertility in males, females, and other sexes, (preferably with descriptions of these causes), or of inability to conceive due to problems during the conception or pre-conception phase, along with incidence percentage or percentage of these problems among the respective populations of unable to conceive or people who has to bear the very depressing misfortune of going through complications, in both males and females.

It would be nice if for each such condition, there were also a table, listing preventive and non preventive solutions, including genetical solutions such as finding exact or close exact matching sperm and egg and using surrogates for child generation or production. This is, in fact, in my very opinion, the solution to many of these problems. It would also be nice if the given techniques used to achieve this were listed in each case. Alternatives welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The [UCI Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php) has one dataset from 2013 called **[Fertility](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Fertility)**

> 100 volunteers provide a semen sample analyzed according to the WHO 2010 criteria. Sperm concentration are related to socio-demographic data, environmental factors, health status, and life habits

The dataset is [multivariate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_analysis), and is likely to be used for regression or classification.

The authors' paywalled paper is [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417412007269).